# Como alterar o código de contribuição para registros duplicados

Tags: sql

Tenho uma consulta que me retorna 04 linhas duplicadas; preciso alterar os códigos da contribuição para que não ocorra erro de Pk.

```
nm_Matricula    Mes_Ano_Referencia  Mes_Ano_Competencia Cod_Contribuicao    DT_pagamento
    32665107            102001             102001               11          2001-10-18
    32665107            102001             102001               11          2001-10-19
    32665107            102001             102001               11          2001-10-22
    32665107            102001             102001               11          2001-10-23



 nm_Matricula   Mes_Ano_Referencia  Mes_Ano_Competencia Cod_Contribuicao    DT_pagamento
    32665107            102001             102001               257         2001-10-18
    32665107            102001             102001               258         2001-10-19
    32665107            102001             102001               259         2001-10-22
    32665107            102001             102001               260         2001-10-23
```

Comment: Poderia postar sua query e formatar melhor a resposta? Para retornar dados não duplicado user o DISTINCT.

Comment: @CidineiaOkamoto: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados? // Observe que as linhas não estão duplicadas, pois diferem na coluna DT_pagamento. // Qual é a regra para alterar valores na coluna Cod_Contribuicao? Isto é, como 11 virou 257,.., 260.

Comment: Estou uitlizando sqlserver 2014, a coluna dt_pagamento eu só inclui para fazer a ordenação.. os campos que preciso fazer o Insert são apenas os nm_Matricula    Mes_Ano_Referencia  Mes_Ano_Competencia Cod_Contribuicao,

Comment: @CidineiaOkamoto: Qual é a regra para alterar valores na coluna Cod_Contribuicao? Isto é, como Cod_Contribuicao=11 virou 257, 258, 259 e 260? // Na tabela de destino, quais colunas fazem parte da chave primária?

Comment: Primeira contribuição 257, segunda 258 e assim sucessivamente..A chave da tabela q recebera esses registros é: nm_Matricula   Mes_Ano_Referencia  Mes_Ano_Competencia Cod_Contribuicao

Answer (score 0):

Considerando-se que o valor da coluna Cod_Contribuicao deve ser renumerado para cada matrícula, ordenado pela data de pagamento, eis esboço do código.

```
-- código #1 v3
with cteRecod as (
SELECT nm_Matricula, Mes_Ano_Referencia, Mes_Ano_Competencia, 
       reCod_Contribuicao= 256 + row_number() over (partition by nm_Matricula order by DT_pagamento asc)
  from tbOrigem
  -- where ...
)
INSERT into tbDestino (colunas)
  SELECT nm_Matricula, Mes_Ano_Referencia, Mes_Ano_Competencia, reCod_Contribuicao
    from cteRecod;
```

Substitua tbOrigem e tbDestino pelos nomes das tabelas.

No comando com a instrução INSERT, substitua *colunas* pelos nomes das colunas na tabela de destino, na mesma sequência do SELECT.

Se for necessário restringir a leitura da tabela de origem, utilize a cláusula WHERE em cteRecod.

Comment: Jose.. Perfeito.. muito obrigada